# BotFramework on Skype For Business does not authenticate

Tags: c#, botframework, skype-for-business

We are developing a bot using the Bot Framework (Microsoft Bot Builder 3.9 on VS2017), we are calling LUIS and QnA Maker APIs and we want to deploy it on Skype for Business Online.
Using the bot framework emulator (no ngrok used),  everything works perfectly on the development environment (localhost).

We have published the API on a local server (intranet) and exposed it through the Azure gateway, a test API endpoint works (/api/test) but the API related to the Bot Framework (/api/messages) does not.

Trying to connect from Fiddler with the below information returns  BotAuthenticator failed to authenticate incoming request!

Request sent:

    `POST: intranet:port/api/messages
    Headers:
    accept: application/json
    content-type: application/json
    content-length: 532
    Host: intranet:port
    Body:
    {
    "type": "message",
    "text": "hi",
    "from": {
    "id": "default-user",
    "name": "User"
    },
    "locale": "en-US",
    "textFormat": "plain",
    "timestamp": "",
    "channelData": {
    "clientActivityId": "1503305115246.7002765593111311.0"
    },
    "entities": [{
    "type": "ClientCapabilities",
    "requiresBotState": true,
    "supportsTts": true,
    "supportsListening": true
    }],
    "id": "ei7ck29k3jj2",
    "channelId": "emulator",
    "localTimestamp": "2017-08-21T11:45:19+03:00",
    "recipient": {
    "id": "4fn4lffkkb5heeam3",
    "name": "Bot"
    },
    "conversation": {
    "id": "5l5dn2diegck"
    },
    "serviceUrl": "http://localhost:port"
    }`

Received:

`HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 57
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="intranet"
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="intranet"
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 21 Aug 2017 14:22:34 GMT`

BotAuthenticator failed to authenticate incoming request!

Then we tried to add the Authorization header with the token generated from https://login.microsoftonline.com/botframework.com/oauth2/v2.0/token but the same problem persists.
The bot was added to Skype for Business but when sending it a message, the reply on Skype for Business Online would be: Error happened in Skype for Business service when reaching bot service.

We have used the Microsft AppId and Password from the settings of the botframework in Azure and included them in the web.config

Any thoughts?